# Aligning DIV within DIV not working

Tags: html, css

I've been writing CSS since it's origin, and I'm stuck. I have a simple DIV within a DIV, class is assigned on the inside DIV, and both class and id are assigned on the outside DIV. There are many DIVs on the page with the same class as the interior one, but there is only one DIV with the id of the exterior one. I have to position the interior DIV, which has elements common to all other DIVs with the same class, but this DIV, inside the DIV with the id assigned, must be positioned uniquely. I can't seem to affect the interior DIV, no matter what I do. The style I'm applying is THE LAST stylesheet loaded on the page, but without effect.

CODE:

```
<STYLE>
    #4columns div.row {display:none;}
</STYLE>

<DIV id="4columns">
    <DIV class="row">
       <DIV class="column_1_4">
           content
       </DIV>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Try not starting the ID with a number. It's valid in HTML, but not in CSS.

Comment: Why caps? where is the CSS that  isn't working? can you rephrase the question to something simple like "i want to align a div with this class relative to this div having this id, like this" ...?

Comment: hard to understand your question.. can you please explain what is the goal you want to achieve

Comment: Jeeze - down-voted because I'm too tired to remember the simplest rule: can't start CSS ids with a number.  Thanks, caeth.

Comment: Yeah, a couple of people seemed to be kind of quick to hit the downvote button. I'll nudge you back over 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In css ID's aren't allowed to start with numbers.

Try this instead:

```
<STYLE>
   #columns4 div.row {display:none;}
</STYLE>

<DIV id="columns4">
   <DIV class="row">
      <DIV class="column_1_4">
         content
      </DIV>
   </DIV>
</DIV>
```